# Django Queryset : How to print second value in queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'd like to print only second value in queryset.

**views.py:**

```
def all_chatroom(request, user_obj):
    current_user = user_obj
    conversations = models.Conversation.objects.filter(participants=user_obj)
    return render(
        request,
        "conversations/all.html",
        {"conversations": conversations, "current_user": current_user},
    )
```

**templates>all.html:**

```
{% extends "partials/base.html" %}

{% block page_name %} 메세지 목록 {% endblock page_name %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container">

{% for conversation in conversations %}
<div class="border">
  {{conversation.participants.all}}
</div>
{% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and the printing value for the template is

```
<QuerySet [<User: master>, <User: test1>]>
<QuerySet [<User: master>, <User: test2>]>
```

for this example, I want to print **test1** and **test2**. how can I print only second value in queryset?

Comment: IMO your template should decide how to render, not what to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second item would be `queryset[1]`

In your template can use `{{ queryset.1}}`

Comment: {{conversation.participants.all.1}} is work for me. very simple, but i don't notice it. Thanks.